# How to rewrite two loops into one LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the next code snippet:

```
var minArea = float.MaxValue;
foreach (var device in deviceDescriptions)
{
    foreach (var zone in device.Zones)
    {
        if (zone.Area.ValueM > 0 && zone.Area.ValueM < minArea)
            minArea = zone.Area.ValueM;
    }
}
```

How can I use (if I can) a single LINQ for this?

I'm confusing in using a loop over `Zones` array.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You sure you only want the "Positive" minimum number ? or negative numbers can also be included as a result ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. An area cannot be negative by definition and I don't need non-filled areas, so condition `zone.Area.ValueM > 0` is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.SelectMany()`,

```
var minArea = deviceDescriptions.SelectMany(x => x.Zones)  //Flatten Nested list
                 .Where(x => x.Area.ValueM > 0)  //Filter for all positive ValueM
                 .Min(x =>x.Area.ValueM);  //Find Min out of all positive ValueM
```

---

[`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8):  Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

[`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8): Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. In your case predication is all positive `ValueM`

[`Min()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netframework-4.8): Returns the minimum value in a sequence of values.

Comment: I think you're missing a logic, it appears the OP doesn't want items below 0, he may be mistaken, but that's the logic he posted.

Comment: You should check `x.Area.ValueM > 0` as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60504853/9071943

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) combine with `Min()` to achieve it.

```
var result = deviceDescriptions.SelectMany(p => p.Zones).Where(x => x.Area.ValueM > 0))
                                                        .Min(x => x.Area.ValueM);
```

---

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and **flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence**

Answer (score 1):

```
var minArea = deviceDescriptions.SelectMany(deviceDescription => deviceDescription.Zones)
                                .Where(zone => zone.Area.ValueM > 0)
                                .Min(zone => zone.Area.ValueM);
```

Comment: The same my idea, the OP should check `x.Area.ValueM > 0` as well.